# Finding Significant Observations from List of Data

Tags: r, statistical-significance, t-test

I have a list of data that consists of the difference between two groups' averages (list C). The two original lists consist of averages across ~20 samples per group (list A and list B). In other words: list A - list B = list C.

I want to find observations in list C such that they are significantly different from 0, which is my null hypothesis (there is no difference between list A and list B). Each observation consists of a single data point. These significant observations should be two tailed so I get negative and positive data points, which indicates either A is significantly greater than B at this observation or vice versa.

I know how to do this with z-scores, but I cannot use them because my sample size is small and my data is likely not normally distributed. Plus, I need the variance.

I'd like to use a t-test, but I'm unsure what statistics I need. I know I need the t-critical value for the alpha level of 0.05 (I want a two-tailed test, so I would need 0.025), but what would I do from here? I would also like to be able to do this in base R.

Comment: Your question is too vague to answer as it stands. Get rid of the word "significant" and explain what your data are and what questions you are trying to answer with statistics.  Is each observation in list C a standalone value? Or the mean of several values?  As you look into this more, beware of multiple comparisons. If you make lots of comparisons, you'll probably get some small p-values just by chance.

Comment: Do you still have list A and list B?